# Google App. Engine - Hosting our Web Application

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting

All,

We are trying to host our web application on Google App. Engine with little success.

Here are the specifics:

<s>The web application is built on HTML5, SVG & Javascript. We are using python 2.6 for upload. We initially used the following tutorial for upload but are getting errors once its uploaded.</s>

Link to tutorial: http://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-app-engine/18801/

<s>We are getting errors in the appcfg.py python file. We are totally clueless how to go about using this so any guidance would be awesome, tutorials would be even more so.</s>

UPDATE: Further to the outcry and Milimetric's helpful post, here is more detail:

We have managed to upload the web application onto the Google App Engine. Going into the dashboard, we can see the application is running (we can see the instance graphs and CPU stats), however, when we execute the custom link to the web application, we only get the 'Hello World' message.

We followed the tutorial by Milimetric & Rolled back the 'appcfg.py' to original state. Following the tutorial, we only made changes to the 'app.yaml' (inserted our application name). We didnt write any custom python script.

We are not getting any errors anywhere, only the message 'Hello World' upon executing the link in the browser window.

Hope the above is more useful.

Cheers,

Comment: love the upvote for the completely unanswerable question.

Comment: Wooble, would love to get YOUR upvote now... :)

Comment: Ok, good.  Have you tried to start changing main.py as I mentioned to start calling your code and rendering your html?  Sorry to be presumptuous but it sounds like you're still expecting your site to just work - google app engine won't do that.  You have to convert everything to the webapp way of thinking.

Comment: @Kayote, also check your dashboard under Administration -> Versions that the correct default site is selected.  Live URI links to each version.

Comment: You say that the only thing you've changed is app.yaml - why are you susprised that the app still prints out "Hello world"?

Comment: @Nick Johnson, clearly Im not getting my head right into this but some instructions would be immensely useful. The above and 2 other tutorials didnt help much so I am looking for help here...

Comment: @Kayote Well, you've uploaded a Hello World app, and it's serving "Hello, world!", which sounds like success to me. The next step would be to follow some of the other tutorials and start writing an app that does more. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Nick Johnson thanks for the feedback Nick. Well we have developed our web application in HTML5, SVG & JS and want to use Google App. Engine but are really struggling to figure out. Milimetric seemed to suggest that we have to do some coding in Python to configure App. Engine to our needs, but we need more documentation about what is configured from where... none of us familiar with python so that doesnt help either. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If any of the following is redundant (or you already went through the steps), let me know and I'll edit.  Just didn't know where to start or how familiar with app engine you were.

1. That tutorial will set up a functional app engine site.  Were you able to get that running without any errors *before* adding your own code?  Try running it locally with the launcher (localhost:8080 by default).
2. To add code, you have to start with the main.py file from the tutorial.  Google app engine applications use the google.appengine.ext.webapp namespace to get started and listen to requests.  In main.py, start with MainHandler and add code there.
3. To add more "routes" to your app, look at the WSGIApplication constructor: webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True) from their tutorial.  So for example, you can have a route go to contact-us like this: webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler), ('/contact-us', ContactUsHandler)], debug=True).
4. As far as tutorials, the google app engine "Getting Started" tutorial is a good primer to get you in the mindset: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/

Answer (score -1):

Google app engine is a cloud computing technology and it is designed for developing and [hosting](http://www.businesswebhostingplans.com) web applications it supports APIs, and frameworks. To solve this issue you ha eto understand app engine completely so to learn more about app engine visit the link above:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine